# hive meta store.db error in spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new user in spark. i am working on remote linux os based pc  using putty. For job purpose i have created a hive table in spark so that i can  manipulate sql queries over it.after my putty session over when i re-enter in my linux pc and creating a table  i have got this errors

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
    java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@79ac37cd, see the next exception
     Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/ubuntu/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/metastore_db.
```

I have just run a query like this

```
spark.sql("CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fact_CMDoubtfulAccount (EntityID STRING,LeaseID STRING,SuiteID String,TxnDate DATE,TxnDateInt INT,Period STRING,BadDebtAmt INT)")
```

Before putty session closed it was working . but it is giving error now . I think i need to do something with meta store. kindly guide how i can solve this problem.I am using spark 2.0
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running on shell and should not declare new sqlContext